# How do you get the product of two case statements

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to combine case statements using the following code and keep encountering errors.

```
SELECT     
        dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group], 
        SUM(CASE
                 WHEN COL_V_COST.EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' 
                  THEN ([CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT] * 
                      (WHEN IsNumeric([TBL_VCOURSE.Length]) 
                        THEN TBL_VCOURSE ELSE 0 END) AS ST_Hours
```

Comment: Well, encountering errors is rather vague.  Perhaps you could clarify a bit?

Comment: It is saying the WHEN and THEN statements are not recognized

Comment: Can you tell us what platform you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, Access)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want this since you have two `CASE` expressions in your original:

```
SELECT  dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group], 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN COL_V_COST.EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' 
            THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT] 
            ELSE 0 END
        * CASE 
            WHEN IsNumeric([TBL_VCOURSE.Length]) = 1 
            THEN TBL_VCOURSE 
            ELSE 0 END
        ) AS ST_Hours
```

Edit, based on your comment your query will be similar to this:

```
SELECT dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group], 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN COL_V_COST.EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' 
            THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT] ELSE 0 END 
        * CASE 
            WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[Length]) = 1 
            THEN COL_TBL_VCOURSE.[LENGTH]
            ELSE 0 END) AS ST_Hours, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN COL_V_COST.EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' 
            THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT]*CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END 
            * CASE 
                WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH]) = 1 
                THEN CAST([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH] AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END) AS ST_Cost
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error saying that the TBL_VCOURSE column name is invalid.

Comment: Do you have a column called `TBL_VCOURSE`?  This was the column that you had in your original post.

Comment: @user1958651 then what column or value do you want to use if `TBL_VCOURSE.Length` is numeric? Do you want to use the `Length` column?

Comment: Yes, now it says I have am issing syntax near an ) the code is 'SELECT     dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group], 
                      SUM(CASE WHEN COL_V_COST.EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT] ELSE 0 END * CASE WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[Length]) 
                      = 1 THEN COL_TBL_VCOURSE ELSE 0 END) AS ST_Hours, SUM(CASE WHEN COL_V_COST.EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT]*CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT) * CASE WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH]) = 1 THEN CAST([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH] AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END) AS ST_Cost'

Comment: Worked, thank you all for all your help. This is going to help me understand the process in the future.